# Re: How to target child nodes in HTML collection

Tags: javascript, foreach, queryselector

I am new to programming and this is my first question. The problem I am having is I am trying to use DOM manipulation on all the child nodes of an html collection. I am expecting the nodes to change background color when they are hovered. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
        let x = 0;

do{
    const square = document.createElement("div");
square.className = "squares";
square.setAttribute("id","block");
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(square);
    x++;
}
while(x < 16);

var container = document.getElementById("container");
var cells = container.childNodes;

cells.forEach(function(){
cells.onmouseover = function(){
cells.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
});
console.log(`${cells.length}`);
```

This doesn't work even though console.log shows 16 child nodes being targeted.

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var cells = container.children[0];
cells.onmouseover = function(){
cells.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

I have tried this and can use index but of course only that cell will change bg color. I want any cell that is hovered to change also.

I am at a loss for what I am doing wrong here. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you use CSS for this? Add a `cell` class to those elements and then: `.cell:hover { background-color: black; }`.

Comment: In my explanation of what I was trying to do I had left out that I want the cells to remain the color they change to and not just during the hover event.

Comment: Ah, ok. You may find event delegation useful. I've documented that in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
There is an issue in your `forEach` cycle.  Consider the following:

```js
cells.forEach(cell => {
  cell.onmouseover = () => {
    cell.style.backgroundColor = "black"
  }
})
```

Note that you need to refer to cycle variable instead of the `cells` array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching listeners to all the squares you can use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) and just have one listener on the container that captures the events from its children as they "bubble up" the DOM.

```js
// Cache the container element, and add a listener to it
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
container.addEventListener('mouseover', handleMouse);

// Create some squares HTML by pushing template
// strings into an array
const html = [];

for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  html.push(`<div class="square">${i}</div>`);
}

// Add that HTML to the container making sure
// we join the array of strings into one string
container.innerHTML = html.join('');

// When a event is fired check that it was
// was from an element with a square class
// and then add an active class to it
function handleMouse(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.square')) {
    e.target.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.container { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px); grid-gap: 0.2em; }
.square { font-size: 1.2em; padding: 0.7em 0.2em; background-color: #565656; color: white; text-align: center; }
.square.active { background-color: thistle; color: black; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)